# Что должно быть вместо "никак не предсказуемой", но не "абсолютно не"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

> Однако реакция нашего конферансье на кусочек картона была никак не
>   предсказуемой.

Может... пусть его живёт?

Comment: Пусть его. Шероховатость стиля должна выдерживаться во всем произведении. Гладко и дурак напишет. )

Comment: От спасибочки! Автор оценит (выспался уже и изучает)! )))

Comment: Большей чуши, чем "шероховатость" стиля, давно не слышал. Это не стиль, а его отсутствие. Такая позиция — потворство халтуре авторов, не желающих работать над текстом.

Comment: Неспящий Глазок, то не халтура, то свой выдержанный стиль...

Comment: Автору дозволено "косить" под шероховатомыслящего рассказчика, был бы только до конца последователен в шероховатости своих словес. "Эдичка" Лимонов в своё время поднялся на сквозящей через всё произведение похабщине. До сих пор дивиденды собирает.

Comment: @Третийглаз, ваши слова – да Достоевскому в уши.

Comment: @Niemand вы так написали, будто он когда-либо был хорошим или хотя бы сносным стилистом, не смешите

Comment: @Третийглаз, я как раз так написал, что он никогда не был сносным стилистом.

Comment: @Niemand да, и это отнюдь не достоинство и не заслуга.

Comment: @Третийглаз, стать великим писателем, будучи никаким стилистом, – это и достоинство, и заслуга.

Comment: @Niemand это ни то, ни другое, а просто абсурд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написал напр. "чертовски" (если не годится пресное "совсем", "и вовсе", "абсолютно/совершенно" и т. п.). "Никак" плохо сочетается с прилагательным, обозначающим *свойство реакции*, хотя вполне годится для выражения "такую его реакцию никак нельзя было предсказать".

Answer (score 2):

Я в таких случаях и говорю, и пишу "совершенно". А "никак" очень неуклюже звучит.

Answer (score 1):

Частица ***никак не*** используется часто, но в большинстве случаев она относится **к глаголам и причастиям,** но не к прилагательным.

Мы говорим при усилении отрицания: *нисколько не интересный* **(наречие степени**), но вряд ли скажем: *никак не интересный*.

***Предсказуемый, непредсказуемый*** ― это отглагольные **прилагательные,** не страдательные причастия настоящего времени (они образованы от глаголов сов. вида).

Поэтому лучше остановиться на уже предложенном варианте **"совершенно непредсказуемый."**

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре:
**непредсказуемый** — такой, что невозможно предсказать, или (о человеке) такой, поступки которого невозможно предугадать, предвидеть.
Непредсказуемые последствия. Непредсказуемое поведение.

Совсем, вовсе, совершенно, полностью, решительно, буквально, напрочь — вместо "никак".